# Identifying Inflection Points for This Strange Function: $y=\frac{3}{11}\left(x^2-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}$

Tags: calculus

Identify the inflection points of
$y=\frac{3}{11}\left(x^2-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}$.

The inflection points are $\left(\pm \sqrt{3},\frac{3}{11}\sqrt[3]{4}\right)$.

However, I'm not sure how to get this answer.

Can someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiate twice you'll get $$\frac{4 (x^2 - 3)}{33 (x^2 - 1)^{\frac{4}{3}}}$$
Set it to zero you have values of $x$. For values of $y$, plug $x$'s into the function.

**Edit:**

By chain rule, you have $y'=\frac{2}{11}(x^2-1)^{\frac{-1}{3}} \times2x = \frac{4x}{11(x^2-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$.

Differentiate agian to obtain $y''$. Quotient rule this time: $$y''=[4\times 11  (x^2-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}-4x\times \frac{11}{3}(x^2-1)^{\frac{-2}{3}}\times2x]/[11^2(x^2-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}]$$
Multiply top and bottom by $(x^2-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}$.

$$y''=\frac{44(x^2-1)-\frac{88}{3}x^2}{11^2(x^2-1)^{\frac{4}{3}}}$$

Simplify a bit you get the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much poyea! May I add this question on: how do you get from the first derivative to the second? Could you please show me step by step? Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you so much poyea. This answer helps me understand how to get to the second derivative. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Sure np. Always work it out first.

Answer (score 0):

Set $y''(x)=0$, and double-check that either $y'''(x)\not=0$ or $y^{(5)}(x)\not=0$, ... You want the lowest-order nonzero derivative beyond the second to be of odd order. Those are sufficient conditions to force an inflection point.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure of that coordinates? We have $$y'(x)=\frac{2}{11}(x^2-1)^{2/3-1}2x$$ and $$y'(x)=\frac{4}{11}\frac{x}{(x^2-1)^{1/3}}$$ and $$y''(x)={\frac {4\,{x}^{2}-12}{33\, \left(  \left( x-1 \right)  \left( x+1
 \right)  \right) ^{4/3}}}
$$ Now solve the equation $$y''(x)=0$$ for $x$ and the coordinates in $$y'''(x)$$
Solving the equation $$y''(x)=0$$ we get $$x=\pm\sqrt{3}$$ and $$y=\frac{3}{11}2^{2/3}$$

Comment: Thank you Dr. Graubner. Yes, I am sure those are the coordinates. If you look at poyea's answer, it is the same as yours except in different form. Perhaps that could help you see that those coordinates are the answers.